# R: Let users use the console while inside a function, record their inputs and react

Tags: r, console, interactive

Is it possible to write a function in R which will hold its execution, giving the users control over the console (while in interactive mode of course), meanwhile recording their inputs, and continuing execution either:

- after a certain input has been made
- or after a certain output has been made
- or a certain duration of time has passed

Example: ask the user a question (without using `readline()` for the answer)

```
question <- function() {
  message("How much is 2 + 2?")
  #let users take control of the console
  #continue to next statement only if they input "2+2", or "4" or a minute has passed
  #meanwhile record their last input similar to ".Last.Value", e.g.:
  startTime <- Sys.time()
  timeout <- FALSE
  lastInput <- lastInput()
  while (eval(parse(text = lastInput)) != 4 & !timeout) {
    if (difftime(Sys.time(), startTime, units = "mins") > 1) {
      timeout <- TRUE
    }
    lastInput <- lastInput()
  }
  if (timeout) {
    stop("Sorry, timeout.")
  } else {
    message("Correct! Let's continue with this function:")
  }
}
```

Where `lastInput()` is a function which "listens" to user input when it changes.

Obviously the above structure is tentative and won't give me what I want, some way to "listen" or "observe" and only react when the user inputs something to the console.

The final user experience should be:

```
> question()
How much is 2+2?
> #I'm the user, I can do whatever
> head(mtcars)
> plot(1:10)
> 3
> 2 + 2
[1] 4
Correct! Let's continue with this function:
```

Am I too optimistic or is there some R magic for this?

Comment: @parth you can use `readline()` for this. In both methods the function waits until the users input something, control over the console is taken away from them, which is not what I want.

Comment: are you looking for interactivity like `swirl` package ?

Comment: Yes, I see `swirl` does something similar. It either listens to a specific input (e.g. "Type 5 + 7:" then you get the console) or you can type `play()` to play with the console as you wish, then whenever you want to return type `nxt()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @parth I have looked at `swirl`'s [source code](https://github.com/swirldev/swirl/blob/master/R/swirl.R) and got acquainted with the `addTaskCallback` function. From the help file:

> `addTaskCallback` registers an R function that is to be called each time a top-level task is completed.

And so we can make R check the users input ("top-level task") with a specific function, responding accordingly.

But since the `swirl` code is very "heavy", I think I need to supply a minimal example:

```
swirllike <- function(...){
  removeTaskCallback("swirllike")
  e <- new.env(globalenv())
  e$prompt <- TRUE
  e$startTime <- Sys.time()
  cb <- function(expr, val, ok, vis, data=e){
    e$expr <- expr
    e$val <- val
    e$ok <- ok
    e$vis <- vis
    # The result of f() will determine whether the callback
    # remains active
    return(f(e, ...))
  }
  addTaskCallback(cb, name = "swirllike")
  message("How much is 2+2?")
}
```

OK, so the `swirllike` function evokes the 2+2 question, but it also declares a new environment `e` with some objects the user needs not know. It then adds the `swirllike` task callback to the task callback list (or rather vector). This "task callback" holds the `cb` function which calls the `f` function - the `f` function will run with every input.

If you run this, make sure you see the `swirllike` task callback with:

```
> getTaskCallbackNames()
[1] "swirllike"
```

Now the `f` function is similar to my sketch in the question:

```
f <- function(e, ...){

  if (e$prompt) {
    if (difftime(Sys.time(), e$startTime, units = "mins") > 1) {
      timeout <- TRUE
      stop("Sorry, timeout.")
    }

    if(!is.null(.Last.value) && .Last.value == 4) {
      message("Correct! Let's continue with this function:")
      e$prompt <- FALSE
      while (!e$prompt) {
        #continue asking questions or something, but for this example:
        break
      }
    }
  }
  return(TRUE)
}
```

And don't forget to remove the `swirllike` task callback with:

```
removeTaskCallback("swirllike")
```